# Remote Debugging Angular running under Azure App Service

Tags: angular, azure-app-service-envrmnt

My first attempt was using Chrome Developer Tools(F12), and setting breakpoints in main.js. That didn't work, on refresh nothing happened. I suspect the sheer size of the main.js(50K lines) could be the issue.

Is it possible to attach Visual Studio 2019 to App Service so I can debug Angular code? Meaning I can just set breakpoints in the .ts files, attach debugger and away I go? So far I'm running into brick walls on this.

Comment: Angular app runs on browser. App Service acts as a file server only and serves the js files to requesting browser. So you cannot debug using Visual Studio. You can of-course debug using F12 debugger tools. In your case you have probably built your angular app in prod mode which does not have source maps. Build your app with source map on and you should be able to debug using F12.